# React checkboxes unchecked wrong value

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to get value from multiple checkboxes into array in React. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Form, InputGroup, Button, Card, Image } from 'react-bootstrap'

function CheckUser() {

    const [choice, setChoice] = useState([]);

    const choosePreference = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();

        let index

        // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
        if (e.target.checked) {
        // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
            choice.push(e.target.value)
        } else {
            // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
            index = choice.indexOf(+e.target.value)
            choice.splice(index, 1)
        }

        console.log(choice);
    }

return(
<Form>
<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="userPreferences">
                    <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Preferences (Tick any below)</Form.Label>
                    {['checkbox'].map((type) => (
                        <div key={`inline-${type}`} className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Artificial Intelligence"
                            name="group1"
                            type={type}
                            id="ArtificialIntelligence"
                            value="Artificial Intelligence"
                            // checked={preferenceList.artificialIntelligence}
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Machine Learning"
                            name="group1"
                            type={type}
                            id="MachineLearning"
                            value="Machine Learning"
                            // checked={preferenceList.machineLearning}
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Natural Language Processing"
                            name="group1"
                            type={type}
                            id="NaturalLanguageProcessing"
                            value="Natural Language Processing"
                            // checked={preferenceList.naturalLanguageProcessing}
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                    {['checkbox'].map((type) => (
                        <div key={`inline-${type}`} className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Multimedia System"
                            name="group2"
                            type={type}
                            id="MultimediaSystem"
                            value="Multimedia System"
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Computer Graphics"
                            name="group2"
                            type={type}
                            id="ComputerGraphics"
                            value="Computer Graphics"
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Visual Processing"
                            name="group2"
                            type={type}
                            id="VisualProcessing"
                            value="Visual Processing"
                            onChange={choosePreference}
                        />
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </Form.Group>
}
</Form>
)

export default CheckUser
```

When I unchecked any value, the array will automatically remove the latest value, not the real unchecked value. For example, if I my checked array is ['Machine Learning', 'Natural Language Processing', 'Artificial Intelligence'], and I unticked 'Natural Language Processing', the new array would be ['Machine Learning', 'Natural Language Processing'].

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code? help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You tried to change state value directly, this is not react way!

You should use `setChoice` to update value and if you need to use previous state value, you should use `setChoice(prevValue => {return newValue;})` format.

Here is the code snippet.

```
const choosePreference = (e) => {
  setChoice(prevChoice => {
    let newChoices = [...prevChoice];
    newChoices = newChoices.filter(e => e !== e.target.value);
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to options array
      newChoices.push(e.target.value)
    }
    console.log(newChoices);
    return newChoices;
  });
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error: ```prevChoice is not an iterable```

Comment: @red17 Are you sure that you initialized state variable by `const [choice, setChoice] = useState([]);`? could you print debug code `console.log(prevChoice, typeof prevChoice);` to let me know?

Comment: yes I did initialize it. The console returns an empty array and btw, it only happens when I am trying to check the second choice @Liki Crus

Comment: @red17 what is the console before throwing error?

Comment: only this ```[] 'object'``` @Liki Crus

Comment: @red17 I updated code and could you check it out again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243792/discussion-between-liki-crus-and-red17).